# Sign and Encrypt SOAP Messages with Apache CXF

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I'm trying to write a "Secure Hello World" web service using Apache CXF also; I should note that I'm kind of new to Java and WS-* stuff.

Basically, what I want to do is a hello-world web service with soap messages to and from this web service **signed and encrypted using x.509 certificate(s)**.

I have already read [the tutorial on Apache CXF site about WS-Security](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html) but; I want to use WS-SecurityPolicy instead of Interceptors.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a blog with details on using Apache CXF: [Adding X.509 security headers to Apache CXF SOAP calls (WS-SecurityPolicy method)](http://web-gmazza.rhcloud.com/blog/entry/cxf-x509-profile)

There's also a [tutorial](https://github.com/gmazza/blog-samples/tree/master/cxf_x509_profile) with source code configured for using the WS-SecurityPolicy Method.

EDIT: fixed broken link, added link to tutorial.

There is now a good overview of the various settings for WS-SecurityPolicy on the [CXF site](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/WS-SecurityPolicy), and it references the link above.

In a nutshell (in case the links are blown away again), the WS-SecurityPolicy is configured similar to the [CXF interceptor method](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/WS-Security) described on the CXF wiki except for a few changes in the cxf.xml and the cxf-servlet.xml:

cxf.xml

```
   <jaxws:client name="{http://myport" createdFromAPI="true">
            <!-- You will need to add the corresponding values to a properties file -->
            <jaxws:properties>
                <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler" value="client.ClientKeystorePasswordCallback"/>        
                <entry key="ws-security.encryption.properties" value=keystore.properties"/>
                <entry key="ws-security.signature.properties" value="keystore.properties"/>
                <entry key="ws-security.encryption.username" value="myservicekey"/>
            </jaxws:properties>
```

cxf-servlet.xml

```
  <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="ws-security.callback-handler">
                <ref bean="myPasswordCallback"/>
            </entry>
            <entry key="ws-security.encryption.properties" value="serviceKeystore.properties"/>
            <entry key="ws-security.signature.properties" value="serviceKeystore.properties"/>
            <entry key="ws-security.encryption.username" value="useReqSigCert"/>
        </jaxws:properties>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the provided link does no longer work, making this answer not useful.

Comment: Apparently they made some changes at the JRoller site, so the URL changed. I did find the original document, and in doing so, noticed that they even included more doc on this at the Apache CXF site, and include a link to the tutorial I had referenced above.

Answer (score 0):

Since web services work over HTTP, you can secure them by using the HTTPS protocol.

Here is a resource that can help point you in the right direction: [Using JAX-WS-Based Web Services with SSL](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-api-for-xml-web-services/using-jax-ws-based-web-services-wit.html)

While this resource is for JAX-WS, you should find that a lot of it will carry over to Apache CXF.

Cheers.