# SOAP encryption using x.509 in java

Tags: web-services, encryption, soap, jax-ws

For past few days I am struggling to create a SOAP web service with encryption in java.
Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve it?

I will show You what I have done till now.

1) Person.java (POJO CLASS)

```
package com.journaldev.jaxws.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Person implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5577579081118070434L;

private String name;
private int age;
private int id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return id+"::"+name+"::"+age;
}

}
```

2) PersonService (Interface)

```
package com.journaldev.jaxws.service;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

import com.journaldev.jaxws.beans.Person;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface PersonService {

@WebMethod
public boolean addPerson(Person p);

@WebMethod
public boolean deletePerson(int id);

@WebMethod
public Person getPerson(int id);

@WebMethod
public Person[] getAllPersons();
}
```

3) PersonServiceImpl (Service Implementation class)

```
package com.journaldev.jaxws.service;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.jws.WebService;

import com.journaldev.jaxws.beans.Person;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.journaldev.jaxws.service.PersonService")  
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

private static Map<Integer,Person> persons = new HashMap<Integer,Person>();

@Override
public boolean addPerson(Person p) {
    if(persons.get(p.getId()) != null) return false;
    persons.put(p.getId(), p);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean deletePerson(int id) {
    if(persons.get(id) == null) return false;
    persons.remove(id);
    return true;
}

@Override
public Person getPerson(int id) {
    return persons.get(id);
}

@Override
public Person[] getAllPersons() {
    Set<Integer> ids = persons.keySet();
    Person[] p = new Person[ids.size()];
    int i=0;
    for(Integer id : ids){
        p[i] = persons.get(id);
        i++;
    }
    return p;
}

}
```

4) SOAPPublisher (Publisher or server)

package com.journaldev.jaxws.service;

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class SOAPPublisher {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/ws/person", new PersonServiceImpl());  
}

}
```

5) SOAPPublisherClient(Client)

```
package com.journaldev.jaxws.service;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

import com.journaldev.jaxws.beans.Person;

public class SOAPPublisherClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    URL wsdlURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/ws/person?wsdl");
    //check above URL in browser, you should see WSDL file

    //creating QName using targetNamespace and name
    QName qname = new QName("http://service.jaxws.journaldev.com/", "PersonServiceImplService"); 

    Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, qname);  

    //We need to pass interface and model beans to client
    PersonService ps = service.getPort(PersonService.class);

    Person p1 = new Person(); p1.setName("Pankaj"); p1.setId(1); p1.setAge(30);
    Person p2 = new Person(); p2.setName("Meghna"); p2.setId(2); p2.setAge(25);

    //add person
    System.out.println("Add Person Status="+ps.addPerson(p1));
    System.out.println("Add Person Status="+ps.addPerson(p2));

    //get person
    System.out.println(ps.getPerson(1));

    //get all persons
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ps.getAllPersons()));

    //delete person
    System.out.println("Delete Person Status="+ps.deletePerson(2));

    //get all persons
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ps.getAllPersons()));

}

}
```

This is what I have done currently.
I want to know how to encrypt Message body using X.509.
Can any one help me with this for both server and client code.

Comment: and - some more links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752075/sign-and-encrypt-soap-messages-with-apache-cxf

Answer (score 0):

There is a well adopted SOAP extension called [WS-Security](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=wss). The standard defines how signed and encrypted messages should look like.

I am not sure which framework you use (cxf, axis2, other?) each framework has different way to set-up the message encryption.

For CXF I suggest start with [this reading](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html) and even there are some [samples](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/systests/ws-security/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/ws/security/) linked.

I am unable to find/link code snippets I had from my previous projects, if I find them, I will try to paste them here when I will be allowed.